# has_many through in rails - saving and retrieving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through

I'm attempting to create a has_many :through relationship for my classes, but am confused about how to actually implement the saving and retrieval of the related data.

I have a Recipe class, Ingredient class, and Amount class that is the :through of the associations. Here are my classes as they stand now:

```
#models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :amounts
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :amounts
end

#models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :amounts
  has_many :recipes, :through => :amounts
end

#models/amounts.rb
class Amounts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipes
  belongs_to :ingredients
end
```

Also, here is a link to a Gist of the rudimentary form for creating Recipes: https://gist.github.com/2820455

And the Gist for the creation code itself:
https://gist.github.com/2820294

When I submit the form, I get this error:

`uninitialized constant Recipe::Amount`

and this app trace:

`app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:57:in 'block in create'
 app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:56:in 'create'`

I'm extremely new to Ruby on Rails and implementing this relationship and getting the Amounts values inserted into the table is boggling my mind...!

Comment: why have you got has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes in ingredient.rb?

Comment: oops. That was a remnant of my old implementation. Removing that now.

Comment: whats the line in the gist on which you are getting the error?

Comment: in the Gist it would be line 23. as the @recipe.save call

Comment: are you also using nested form? and how are you passing the params in this case @ingredients = params[:ingredients]?

Comment: The name of the select box is "ingredients[]", so an array of the selected options is passed into the function as params[:ingredients]

Comment: belongs_to has to be singular in your amount.rb file, eg:- it will be belongs_to :recipe and belongs_to :ingredient

Comment: Oh wow...what an oversight on my part. Thank you. Everything seems to be in order now...but how to add extra information to the Amounts model? To get information about the association, i.e. the amount of a certain Ingredient in a Recipe?

Comment: you can write methods in your through model and access it http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

belongs_to needs to be singular, in your amount.rb change it to look like this :-

## models/amounts.rb

```
class Amounts < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```